# Science fiction movie about a guy with superpowers and two pistols

Tags: story-identification, movie

Not sure if the guy is black or white, but it’s science fiction and the guy has some sort of super powers. He uses 2 pistols to kill enemies. The pistols are his super powers.

He will be in the woods somehow, and will befriend a little boy. The citizens of the island dont like him and want him dead.

The movie isnt tooo old but not new either. Somewhere between 2010-2016.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0399201/?ref_=ttpl_pl_tt?

Comment: [TV Tropes: Superhero Packing Heat
aka: Guns As Superpowers](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/SuperheroPackingHeat?from=Main.GunsAsSuperpowers) - One of these, perhaps?

Comment: I can’t help but think of [*Equilibrium*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0238380/).

Comment: Wanted, maybe Hitman. Link to Wanted. If more info could be provided, it would help to identify thw movie. What type of island? How did the pistols/guns looked? What other characters appear? Was there an organization? https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0493464/?ref_=m_ttls_tt_84

Answer (score 6):

Description is really vague... But if we convert "pistols" into "revolvers", then plot matches very well with *The Dark Tower".

[image]

https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1648190/

Comment: And those are magical revolvers, so it's fair to call them his superpowers.

Comment: @Adamant - in this movie? Hard to say, actually. I think no, but he's using them extremely well, so it looks like magic.

Comment: They're magic in the books. Made from Excalibur or some such. Of course, Roland is also a  great shooter.

Comment: @Adamant - Ah. That would explain a lot. Movie, I think, skipped that bit. Also, if we follow the name - Roland - then the sword would be actually Durendal. So definitely "some such". OP, however, refers to a movie, not a book. I am interested, though. Thanks for that!!